# How compatible are Islamic teachings with the “String Theory”?

Tags: science

Many supporters of the String theory argue that there are beings in other Dimensions. Are these arguments compatible with the Teachings of Islam? Are there “higher” dimensional beings in Islam?

Comment: String theory is even at this point still very theoretical. And concerning the other dimensions, or universes, it is said that our universe has *just enough black matter* for planets, stars and galaxies to form and stay stable. So maybe there are other universes; but maybe the other universes are the other 6 samawat (skies) that Allah talks about. We don't know yet. We don't know. It is said in some aya in the quran still that Allah may already have made some creatures before us, or may not, I will have to find it again, iyw.

Comment: But if there is something for sure to say, is that science however theoretical and complicated it gets is never against religion, especially the religion of Allah. We are just learning about the creation of Allah, not something else, so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

No. Islam does not teach theories. Islam presents facts.
Islam means submission. Submitting oneself to his/her Creator in obedience and believing that our knowledge is limited and Islam is superior over our intellect.